# For what translation groups $G$ of $\mathbb C$ is $\mathbb C / G$ compact?

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis

If $G$ is a cyclic translation group (generated by $z \mapsto z + \tau$ for some $\tau \in \mathbb C$), then obviously $\mathbb C/G$ is not compact, since if $\tau = 0$ then $\mathbb C/G \cong \mathbb C$, and if $\tau \neq 0$ then $\mathbb C / G \cong [0, 1) + i\mathbb R$, which is also not compact.

The converse is not true; if $G$ is generated by $z \mapsto z + 1$ and $z \mapsto z + \pi$, then $\mathbb C / G$ is again not compact, even though $G$ is not cyclic.

So when is it the case that $\mathbb C/G$ is compact? How can we characterize such translation groups $G$?

Comment: I would conjecture that any cyclic translation group $G$ containing translations $z\mapsto z+\tau_1$ and $z\mapsto z+\tau_2$ where $\tau_1,\tau_2\in\mathbb{C}$ are linearly independent (as a vector space of $\mathbb{R}$) would result in $\mathbb{C}/G$ compact. My thinking for this that modding out the translation group generated by $z\mapsto z+1$ and $z\mapsto z+i$ results in a complex torus, and more generally so does modding out any "linearly independent" pair. Already there's no way to "escape to "infinity," so modding out more translations shouldn't affect compactness.

Comment: @Blake yeah, I think that's correct. I wonder if that completely characterizes the $G$'s where $\mathbb C/G$ is compact. It sounds reasonable that $\mathbb C/G$ would be non-compact if all of the translation offsets in $G$ lie on a single line in $\mathbb C$.

Comment: I'm not sure. There's a possibility you could run into something nasty if $G$ is not finitely generated, but it seems that modding out only finitely generated translation groups would result in some sort of polygon, which would be compact.

Comment: For easier searches, the keyword is "co-compact": https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cocompact_group_action

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We may as well ask the more general question "For which subgroups 
$G \subset (\mathbb{R}^n, +)$ is $\mathbb{R}^n / G$ compact?".
The answer is that it is compact if and only if the linear span of $G$ is
all of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

If $G$ spans $\mathbb{R}^n$, it contains a basis, so we can find a linear 
isomorphism $f: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ such that 
$\mathbb{Z}^n \subset f[G]$. Then 
$\mathbb{R}^n/G \cong (\mathbb{R}^n/\mathbb{Z}^n) / (f[G]/\mathbb{Z}^n)$, which must be compact because 
$\mathbb{R}^n/\mathbb{Z}^n \cong \mathbb{T}^n$ is already compact.

If $G$ does not span $\mathbb{R}^n$, there is a linear isomorphism $h: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R} \times\mathbb{R}^{n-1}$ such that 
$h[G] \subset \{0\} \times \mathbb{R}^{n-1}$. In that case, since $\mathbb{R}$ is locally compact, we have
$\mathbb{R}^n/G \cong \mathbb{R} \times (\{0\} \times \mathbb{R}^{n-1})/h[G]$, which is not compact because $\mathbb{R}$ is not.

Since $\mathbb{C}$ is a two-dimensional over $\mathbb{R}$, this means
that $\mathbb{C}/G$ is compact if and only if there are two elements
of $G$ that are linearly independent over $\mathbb{R}$, as suggested in
Blake's comments.

Comment: Interesting use of the Third Isomorphism Theorem! I don't think I've ever actually seen it in use before.